# Android add java library module dependency during test

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, robolectric

I try to tun my unit test in android studio 1.2.1.1 using robolectric 3.0-rc2.

My app is split in multiple module.

|---- app (the android app) 
|---- common (java library module)

When I run my test I have some references to common module in my activity.
But test failed cause of it with a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

So I'm wondering how I should add my module in my dependency.

I tried to add

```
testCompile(':common')
```

but nothing changed.

Comment: How are you running the test? Android Studio or command line (and what command)?

Comment: I launch from Android studio.